# flip and swap alternate column in 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, swap

This is my 2d list

```
array = ([a,b, c,d, e,f ,g,h], [s,t, u,v, w,x ,y,z])
```

I would like the output to be

```
array = ([g,h, e,f, c,d, a,b] ,[y,z, w,x, u,v, s,t])
```

I was using below to flip the array, but i am stuck to do alternate swap. can anyone help me. Thanks.

```
array = np.flip(array,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can play with [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
array = np.array([['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'],
                  ['s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']])

x,y = array.shape
np.flip(array.reshape((x, -1, 2)), axis=1).reshape(x,y)
```

output:

```
array([['g', 'h', 'e', 'f', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b'],
       ['y', 'z', 'w', 'x', 'u', 'v', 's', 't']], dtype='<U1')
```